# How to find a image button using SWTBot

Tags: swtbot

I have a SWT Button, it does not contains text, just an image. I searched for methods, but I can't find a way to press it.

Comment: Could you please show what you've researched ?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the index -0-based order of the button in all the available buttons in this context- of the button, you can try `bot.button(index)`. But as UI can change that, I strongly recommend the solution proposed by @alt3.

Comment: But if you don't have access to the SUT code OR SUT uses some Eclipse built-in controls (i.e. text below the title in the shells. You can set in in the plugin, but you don't have access to the widget itself), than indexes are the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the button with an id:

```
yourButton.setData("org.eclipse.swtbot.widget.key", "yourButtonId");
```

Then, call the following method through the bot:

```
bot.buttonWithId("yourButtonId").click();
```